# Escaping characters in column names in a PostgreSQL query?

Tags: sql, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I have a query that I am using that works fine in MySQL but having problems with it working on Postgres. I'm getting a syntax error that I am sure has a simple solution but can't find anything on here about it.

It's pretty clear that the problem has to do with the digit 1 in the first case when.

```
SELECT *, 
(
 (case when 1stFarmers > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
  (case when OldMcDonald > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
   (case when NewMcDonald > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 

) as num_fruits

FROM (SELECT
  fruit, sum(farmers),
  sum(case when farmer = '1stFarmers' then harvest_count else 0 end) AS 1stFarmers,
  sum(case when farmer = 'OldMcDonald' then harvest_count else 0 end) AS Old_McDonald,
  sum(case when farmer = 'NewMcDonald' then harvest_count else 0 end) AS New_McDonald
FROM fruits
GROUP BY
  farmer) ft
```

---

The error I am getting back:

```
syntax error at or near "stFarmers"
  Position: 27
(
 (case when 1stFarmers > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
             ^
  (case when OldMcDonald > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use double quotes `"` to escape identifiers (in your case, column names) that contain numbers:

```
(case when "1stFarmers" > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) +
```

Comment: @icm: here is the relevant link to the manual: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-syntax-lexical.html#SQL-SYNTAX-IDENTIFIERS it always pays of to read it instead of blindly trying stuff ;)